# Separating or grouping Values of a column into different categories in R

Tags: r, regression, economics

[image: screenshot of the Dataset]

Good morning everyone.
Please I do have a problem that I have not been able to solve for quite some time now.(**please take a look at the image link to see a screen shot of my data set)** **https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2eTM.jpg**

I have a column of data **(status)** containing two set of values (1 and 2). **These are dummies representing two categories (or status) of dependent Variables (say Pp and Pt) that I need for a regression.** **their actual values are contained the last column Pp.Pt (Pp.Pt is just a name nothing more)**.

I need to run two separate regressions each using either Pp or Pt (**meaning using their respective values in the Pp.Pt column **(each value in the last column is either of status 1 or of status 2)**** . **My question is How do I separte them  or group them into  these two categories 1= Pp and 2 = Pt so that i could clearly identitify and group them.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2eTM.jpg

Thank you very much for your kind help.
Best
Ludovic

Comment: Please use `dput(head(df, 30))` where `df` is the name of your data.frame and copy and paste the output from the console into your question.

Comment: Hi thanks Please are you not able to see the screen shot that I have uploaded?

Comment: Hi please do take a look at a screenshot of my dataset to 
 get a better understanding https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2eTM.jpg

Comment: We do not need a picture of your data but numbers as sample data to work with therefore please do as @hello_friend asks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this approach can fix your issue

```
yourdata %>%
mutate(classofyourcolumn=ifelse(columntosplit<quantile(columntosplit,0.5),1,0))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Greatly appreciate it

Comment: welcome, if it solves your problem please sign as approved

Comment: Please samet i have edited my question and added a screen shot of my data set please could you take a look if you can. You would be better able to understand my problem

Comment: hi, actually I don't clearly understand by saying "splitting". I assumed that you mean "discretization". I edited my code to discretize your pp.pt column from quantile 0.5

Comment: you want them as before the point and after the point, right ? if so, I will update my answer. I ask what will be your criteria while splitting pp.pt column

Comment: No samer please tell me are you able to see the screen shot of my dataset I have uploaded? Basically I have a column of data containing values of differents status. Each of these values belong to either status 1 or status 2 . I need a way of having them separated so that I could use status1= Pp as dependent variable 1 and status2= dependent variable Pt

Comment: please take a look at the Image link    https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2eTM.jpg

Comment: @ThinkingEconomist, dear mr ludovic, please please please share a little piece of your data (not a screenshot). I promise we will fix your problem

Comment: Samet the problem is i do not know how to do that here. if you could guide me through how to do that i would

Comment: in the simpliest way, just select 10 or a bit more rows, then copy and paste here

Answer (score 1):

`Split-Apply-Combine` method :

```
# Using the mtcars dataset as an example: 
df <- mtcars

# Allocate some memory for a list storing the split data.frame: 
# df_list => empty list with the number of elements of the unique
# values of the cyl vector
df_list <- vector("list", length(unique(df$cyl)))

# Split the data.frame by the cyl vector: 
df_list <- split(df, df$cyl)

# Apply the regression model, return the summary data: 
lapply(df_list, function(x){
  summary(lm(mpg ~ hp, data = x))
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you I greatly appreciate it

Comment: @ThinkingEconomist no worries, you will find this computational pattern extremely useful. As is stackoverflow etiquette, if you have found my answer useful/answers your original question (as posted) please upvote and accept it.

Comment: Hi please take a look at the screen shot of my data set, you will be better able to understand
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2eTM.jpg

Comment: @ThinkingEconomist use `dput()` as I have described -- as is standard stack overflow practice.