# Grouping Values of a column into different categories in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression, economics

Please I am new to R and here as well. I am unable to upload an image of my dataset at the moment.

Here is my problem:

I have a dataset containing two columns that are of particular interest to me. One of them `Status` contains identifiers (1 and 2) 1 represents the variable Y1  and 2 represents the variable Y2. I need to run two separate regressions using Y1 and Y2 as dependent variables.

The other column `Y1andY2` contains the respective value of Y1 and Y2 all merged into a single column. So I need a way of separating or grouping those values into Y1 and Y2. This would allow me to run the two separate regressions.

```
Status   Y1andY2
1        1.521174
2        1.873917
2        2.116277
1        1.803262
1        3.725778
2        2.285313
1        2.732088
1        2.799842
2        2.976210
1        1.337500
1        1.259238
```

Your help would be greatly appreciate.

Thanks
Cheers
Ludov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to convert your data to wide format so that instead of having a Status ('key') column and a Y1andY2 ('values') column you want one column with the Y1 values and one with the Y2 values. This will make your df have half as many rows.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = 'Status', values_from = 'Y1andY2')
```

Comment: Thank you very much Elle. Please could kindly take a look at my first question where i give more details? I am unable to upload image https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67196520/separating-or-grouping-values-of-a-column-into-different-categories-in-r

Comment: Hi, that seems like the same thing with `names_from = status` and `values_from` = Pp.Pt`. Did the answer solve your problem?

Comment: here is the screenshot of my dataset     https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2eTM.jpg

Comment: no unfortunately. it did not. Please Elle do take a look at the link of my dataset. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2eTM.jpg

Comment: I did. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: you see the last column that I called Pp.Pt. It has the values I want to use as dependent variable for a regression (Pp and Pt) . Pp =1 and Pt= 2.  The problem is the column contains both  Pp and Pt  variables. I need a way of grouping each variable in a separate group since a need to run Two separate regressions.

Comment: Do you want them each in their own column?

Comment: That's what `pivot_wider()` does.